# webkit-filters on Mobile Safari?

Tags: css, webkit, mobile-safari

It seems to me I remember seeing webkit-filters working in Mobile Safari, but I'm having trouble with it. This CSS code shows up fine in my desktop browsers, but not on my iPhone. Any clues? I'm on iOS v6.

All I'm doing is adding/removing classes via jQuery.

```
.redtint {
  -webkit-filter: saturate(15) hue-rotate(330deg) brightness(110%);
  -moz-filter: saturate(5) hue-rotate(330deg) grayscale(110%);
}
```

When I look at my elements on desktop it shows redtint with the webkit settings, but when I look at them on my phone (using Adobe Edge Inspect), redtint is blank.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out to be a difference in interpretation of the brightness filter between Chrome and Mobile Safari.

I was primarily testing on my desktop in Chrome. Everything worked fine if I used 100% for the baseline value (no change in brightness) with 80% being darker and 120% being lighter.

Mobile Safari is using a baseline of 0% for no change, with -20% being darker and 20% being brighter.

My webapp is only for iPhones, so I won't have to screw around with workarounds.